# onClick() does not work after appying dexguard. Is there any way to solve this?

Tags: android, dexguard

i am using `dexguard` to secure my app. Recently i updated the `dexgaurd` version 
from **8.0.1** to **8.2.15**. Earlier everything is working fine before the update. But with the version **8.2.15** when i apply **dexguard**, onCick method does not works in one of fragment **SettingsFragment**, for all of the other **Fragments** it works fine. However the code and method of implementing **onClick()** is same for all **Fragments**. But for **SettingsFragment** it's not working. Please help.

Here is my `onClick` method in **SettingsFragment**

```
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.relSignOut:
                    mCallback.doSignOut();
                    break;
//                case R.id.relEditProfile:
//                    loadManageProfile();
//                    break;
                case R.id.btn_edit_profile:
                    loadManageProfile();
                    break;
                case R.id.relDynamicFxRate:
                    parent.startSetExchangeAlertActivity();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @QandilTariq thanks for you comment, code for SettingsFragment ?

Comment: share the code of onclick which u implemented(setting frag...) sir

Comment: yes please share the setting fragment code.

Comment: Please check the question,i have edited it

Comment: Please kick off the switch statement and replace it with if-else. May seem a bit unscientific and illogical , but I think it will work.

If it doesn't work, try to check different buttons with other methods (like position) rather that `id`

Comment: Thanks @Toaster,i dont how. But it worked for me. Many thanks

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it worked. Thanks

Comment: I already did it @Toaster

Comment: Hehe, no , I've written an answer. If it worked, please accept it and upvote.

Comment: The reason it fails is probably due to resource optimization which remaps resource IDs. Normally these remapped resource IDs get replaced everywhere in the code, but it might go wrong in case of switch statements. You can disable resource optimization like that: -optimizations !resource/compaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Converting my comment to answer)

Please kick off the switch statement and replace it with if-else. May seem bit unscientific and illogical, but I worked for me many times.

I don't know if it's a possible bug in the compiler or in Android or not, but sometimes rejecting switch statement only doesn't help. Then I've to replace `view.getId()` with `view.getPosition()` and check by order or something like this to make it work anyway.

> From T.Neidhart's comment: The reason it fails is probably due to resource optimization which remaps resource IDs. Normally these remapped resource IDs get replaced everywhere in the code, but it might go wrong in case of switch statements. You can disable resource optimization like that: -optimizations resource/compaction –

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude obfuscation of `onClick` methods like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    public void onClick (android.view.View);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,but I did this already. It didnt help. If it obfuscating onClick() then it should have obfuscate all onCilicks(). In my case onClick() works fine with all fragments but only in SettingsFragments its not working.

Comment: Is it possible to you not using onClick? I mean set listener directly to the target widgets.